# How to create a command that uses vim-function?

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

Say that we have a function:

```
function StripTrailingWhitespace()
  if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
    normal mz
    normal Hmy
    %s/\s\+$//e
    normal 'yz<CR>
    normal `z
  endif
endfunction
```

How to map this function to `StripTrailingWhiteSpace` command so that we can run `:StripTrailingWhiteSpace` instead of `:call StripTrailingWhiteSpace()` ?

How to do the same for functions with arguments ?

The reason for doing that is: we get commands as completion window of `fzf/vim-clap/coc` plugins. And it's more align with vscode's `cmd+shift+p` functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:command` command is what you are looking for.

Please read `:h command` for details. E.g. range handling, arguments handling etc.

In your case:

```
command! StripTrailingWhiteSpace call StripTrailingWhiteSpace()
```

Comment: ! Is probably not necessary